# Multiline regex match in PowerShell with or without lookahead

Tags: regex, powershell, visual-studio-code, multiline

I'm trying to format markdown file so that there is one empty line after the headings, the file is `UTF8` encoded with `CRLF` line breaks, here is example file:

````
## DESCRIPTION
description entry...

## EXAMPLES

### EXAMPLE 1
```
some example here...
```

## OUTPUTS
## NOTES
````

Here I want to find all headings that are not followed by empty line,
assuming file name is `file.md` here is sample code whose only purpose is to match headings that lack empty line:

```
$FileData = Get-Content file.md

if ($FileData -match '(?m)^#+\s.*$\s*^.+') { $Matches }
```

Expected output:

```
## DESCRIPTION
### EXAMPLE 1
## OUTPUTS
```

Actual output:

`<no output>`

Other regex attempts are as follows, but none works:

```
(?m)^#+\s.*\n*^.+
(?m)^#+\s.*\r\n*^.+
^#+\s.*$(?=\n^.+)
^#+\s.*$(?=\r\n^.+)
^#+\s.*$(?=\s^.+)
```

Nothing is matched, these regexes are supposed to work because with little modification for VSCode they work just fine, but not in PowerShell, for example:

`^#+\s.*$(?=\n^.+)` work just fine for VSCode engine, the `\n` is used for VSCode but in PowerShell `(?m)` should be used or `\r\n` or `\n` but none of these constructs works.

I'm sure somebody has answer to this, but please include in your answer why both the `(?m)` and `\r\n` don't work and how to make use of both of them in this specific scenario?

**EDIT:**

According to comment by Wiktor I tried his suggestion but it doesn't give me the result I want:

```
$FileData = Get-Content file.md -Raw

foreach ($Line in $FileData) {
if ($Line -match '^#+\s.*$(?=\s^.+)') { $Matches }  
}
```

I tried all sample regexes posted here, but the output is wrong or no output for all of them

Comment: You need to read the whole file into a variable, `$FileData = Get-Content file.md -Raw`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question, still having problems.

Comment: I see, that `if ($FileData -match '(?m)^#+\s.*$\s*^.+') { $Matches }` returns the first match, need to figure out how to get all matches.. thanks for your comment!

Comment: You are still doing it wrong: you need to send the whole text as one string to the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you send the whole file as a single variable to regex usign `-Raw` option.

Then, you need to make sure the pattern works in multiline mode, you can use

```
(?m)^#+[\p{Zs}\t].*$(?=\n.)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%23%2B%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D.*%24%28%3F%3D%5Cn.%29&i=%23%23%20DESCRIPTION%0D%0Adescription%20entry...%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%20EXAMPLES%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%23%20EXAMPLE%201%0D%0A%60%60%60%0D%0Asome%20example%20here...%0D%0A%60%60%60%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%23%20OUTPUTS%0D%0A%23%23%20NOTES).

- `(?m)` - now, `^` matches start of a line and `$` matches the end of a line
- `^` - start of a line
- `#+` - one or more `#` chars
- `[\p{Zs}\t]` - any horizontal whitespace
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than a newline/line feed
- `$` - end of line (position before a newline char)
- `(?=\n.)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is a newline and any char other than a newline immediately to the right of the current location.

In Powershell, you can use

```
 Get-Content 'c:\1\1.txt' -Raw | Select-String '(?m)^#+[\p{Zs}\t].*$(?=\n.)' -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Value}
```

Comment: Hey friend thank you so much, I've done experiments with your code and when I visit Poland this is the code upon which we'll have a beer!  `$FileData | Select-String '(?m)^#+\s.+$(?=\n[\w|``]+)' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }`